# select a set of products present in all stores all weeks

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I have a database in postgresql with `product_id, store_id, week, price_avg, price_min, price_max` and I want to select a set of homogeneous products that it is present in a set of stores and in the same weeks.

I have tried some approaches but it´s difficult since I have 22 million of prices, 2645 different stores and data for 13 weeks.

**The goal** is to select a set of 20 product_ids that are present in all 13 weeks of  information and that they appear in a set of 10 stores all the time.

First I thought on splitting the database in tables per store and then do an inner join with product_id. But that's costly for SQL.

Second, I took first two weeks in a table. and I run a

```
select 
    count() as quantity, f2.product, f2.key_all_stores 
from 
    database f2 
group by 
    product_id, key_all_stores 
having 
    count() = 2
```

The having count 2 keeps those products in both week. and then with those products selected I run the following:

```
select 
    count(), product_id 
from 
    (select 
         count() as quantity, f2.product_id, f2.clave_todo_junto 
     from 
         fer f2 
     group by 
         producto, key_all_stores 
     having 
         count() = 2) as subquery 
group by 
    subquery.product_id 
having 
    count() = 4
```

The issue with these two queries is that I am looking at two weeks and doing a sample with 4 different stores.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Looks like homework... What did you try so far?

Comment: Don't tell in comment. Update your question with your queries.. Better provide some data and desired result for better answer

Comment: Hi. Please read & act on [mcve]. Including:  Show relevant queries you can do. Develop/debug with representative data. Show that your program calculates what you expect it to as it goes through (sub)expressions. PS "present in all" suggests relational division. Read about it & expressing it in SQL. PS What do you mean "appear all the time"? "I am looking at ..." does not elicidate/explain "The issue with these two queries". Please use enough words, phrases & sentences & references to parts of examples to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a database in postgresql with **product_id, store_id, week, price_avg, price_min, price_max** …
>   The Goal is to select a set of 20 product_ids that are present in all 13 weeks of information and that they appear in a set of 10 stores all the time.

If all of these columns are still inside a single table, as stated, you may try the following shortcut :

```
WITH shortlist(product_id,store_id,week) AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT product_id,store_id,week
               FROM yourtable
              WHERE store_id IN (store1,store2,store3,store4)
                AND week     IN (week1,week2,week3,…)
)

  SELECT product_id,count(*)
    FROM shortlist
GROUP BY product_id
  HAVING count(*) >= 130
```

You may dismiss the **AND** row if you're sure that your table contains nothing else than the 13 quoted weeks. Specify the requested store ids the upper one and replace *yourtable* by the actual name.

The point here is that making a DISTINCT pre-selection first with only concerned fields will get rid of every duplicated row if you have multiple data regarding price for a given price-store-week combination.

Given this, a product that appear all of these 13 weeks in all 10 different stores should produce exactly 130 entries. Thus the final count.

Comment: I have checked and I don´t have such a product that is present in all stores. I cannot do it with a multiplication of week times stores.